# How do I make an integer 'bigger'?

Tags: c#, debugging, integer, int64, iec10967

I am a C# beginner and I am working on a calculator in Windows Forms.

I've encountered a problem in which I get one of those debug blurbs after 10 or more digits are inputed into the interface. It says something about a system overflow exception, but I don't really understand.

Can someone please tell me a simple way to make an `Int64` variable?

Comment: You want an 64-bit integer? `var i = 999999999999L;` Or do you want something else?

Comment: Show some code. We can show you how to fix your code.

Comment: Int64 or long, or really just use decimal

Comment: C# `long` type is a 64-bit integer.

Comment: Please next time instead of saying "some blurb" please copy message and paste it directly to the post. Copy/paste should not need ability to read, but it will make question more concrete.

Comment: Also it would be useful to show some code where you already "make a variable". It is unclear what exactly is a problem to use `Int64` as a type of variable (like `Int64 myVaraible;` or `long myVariable;`)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BigInteger` from `Numerics` library.

you need to add the `System.Numerics` library.
Folow the below steps to add it.

**Step 1:** Right Click on your Project `References`
**Step 2:** Click on `AddReference...`
**Step 3:** from the FrameWork category you need to select the `System.Numerics`

From the Code you can use the same library :

Try This:

```
using System.Numerics;
BigInteger value = new BigInteger(99999999999999999999999999);
```

Comment: While correct for gigantic numbers.. the OP just wants to know how to declare a 64-bit integer.

Comment: Why not just use `long` type instead `bigint`

Comment: +1. @SimonWhitehead - "10 or more digits" will quickly exhaust `long` /`System.Int64` type (which OP apparently already knows), so going directly to unlimited length looks better approach for calculator.

Comment: Fair enough. Running before being able to walk is the new thing these days I've noticed :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `BigInteger` datatype instead of `int` datatype, this should be able to hold a very large number.

Comment: ..and what namespace does the `bigint` type reside in? ... Certainly not `System`...

Comment: `System.Numerics.BigInteger`-can be used in .NET 4.0 or after [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)

Comment: The reason I called your mistake out was because the OP says "I am a C# beginner". Saying use `bigint` is likely to confuse them.. given that `bigint` isn't actually a type in C#.. rather `BigInteger` is. Small mistake.. but important for the OP.